# Jetty's DispatcherType (and 1000 other undocumented things)

Tags: jetty

Can someone tell me, what [DispatcherType](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/DispatcherType.html) is doing?

Seems to be an important configuration.

Class usage didn't helped me as well by pointing to things such as [ServletContextHandler#addFilter](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html#addFilter%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.EnumSet%29), which is "documented" with the wise words: `convenience method to add a filter`.

---

In general, any chance to "understand" the *undocumented* Jetty API without *code-example-search-fun* or *try-and-fail-and-wonder*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is also a setting in web.xml; and probably has been in existence for quite some time.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28959/filters.htm#BCFIEDGB

## Configuring Filters for Forward or Include Targets

This section provides a few sample configurations to have a filter act on forward or include targets. We start with the filter declaration, followed by alternative filter mapping configurations:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

To execute MyFilter to filter an include target named includedservlet:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>includedservlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note that the include() call can come from any servlet (or other resource) in the application. Also note that MyFilter would not execute for a direct request of includedservlet, unless you have another  element with the value REQUEST.

To execute MyFilter to filter any servlet directly requested through a URL pattern "/mypath/", or to execute it to filter any forward target that is invoked through a URL pattern starting with "/mypath/":

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/mypath/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Also, the default is Request; read appliesTo(...) method on following page:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/8.0.0.M0/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/FilterMapping.java#FilterMapping.0_dispatches

Comment: Well, I must agree, it makes sence, that Request is default ;)

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Asad's answer, the dispatcher isn't Jetty specific, it's part of the servlet specification up to version 2.5. Here is the the official description for the dispatcher values from [web-app_2_5.xsd](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd):

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="dispatcherType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>

The dispatcher has four legal values: FORWARD, REQUEST, INCLUDE,
and ERROR. A value of FORWARD means the Filter will be applied
under RequestDispatcher.forward() calls.  A value of REQUEST
means the Filter will be applied under ordinary client calls to
the path or servlet. A value of INCLUDE means the Filter will be
applied under RequestDispatcher.include() calls.  A value of
ERROR means the Filter will be applied under the error page
mechanism.  The absence of any dispatcher elements in a
filter-mapping indicates a default of applying filters only under
ordinary client calls to the path or servlet.

        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>

    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="javaee:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="FORWARD"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="INCLUDE"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="REQUEST"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="ERROR"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```